# How to make a bullet shoot in the direction of the gun in mobile?

Tags: unity, 2d

I am working in unity with c#. I am working on a 2D platformer for mobile. The way I currently have it setup is one joystick that moves the charatcer makes the charatcer arm rotate and make the charatcer shoot the gun when pressed. Which all workd fine. But the problem I am having is the bullets from the gun are not going in the correct direction. Currently the bullets go to the rigtht no matter where I point the gun. I have tried in the raycats to use transform.right and transform.forward. All end up with the same result. the firepoint for the gun is an empty game object and the firepoint in the script is an tranfrom. It is an child of the gun so I thought it would use the same rotation but I am not sure of I need to say what rotation I need for the raycast. I tried changing it to an GameObject in the script but I got the same results. If someone could please help it would be grealty appreciated!!!

Here is the shoot function with the raycast.

```
public void Shoot ()
{
    Vector3 firePointPosition = new Vector3 (firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y, 0f);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (firePointPosition, firePoint.transform.right, 100, whatToHit, 0f);

    Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, (firePointPosition)*100, Color.cyan); 
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, hit.point, Color.red);
        Enemy enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.DamageEnemy(Damage);
            //Debug.Log("We hit " + hit.collider.name + "and did " + Damage + "damage");
        }
    }

    if (Time.time >= timeToSpawnEffect)
    {
        Vector3 hitPos;
        Vector3 hitNormal;

        if (hit.collider == null)
        {
            hitPos = (firePointPosition) * 30;
            hitNormal = new Vector3(9999, 9999, 9999);
        }
        else
        {
            hitPos = hit.point;
            hitNormal = hit.normal;
        }



        Effect(hitPos, hitNormal);
        timeToSpawnEffect = Time.time + 1 / effectSpawnRate;
    }
}
```

And here is the effect method

```
void Effect (Vector3 hitPos, Vector3 hitNormal)
{
    Transform trail = Instantiate (BulletTrailPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as Transform;
    LineRenderer Lr = trail.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    if (Lr != null)
    {
        Lr.SetPosition(0, firePoint.position);
        Lr.SetPosition(1, hitPos);

    }

    Destroy(trail.gameObject, 0.04f);

    if (hitNormal != new Vector3(9999,9999,9999))
    {
        Transform hitParticle = Instantiate(HitPrefab, hitPos, Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3.right, hitNormal))as Transform;
        Destroy(hitParticle.gameObject, 1f);
    }

    Transform clone = Instantiate (MuzzleFlashPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as Transform;
    clone.parent = firePoint;
    float size = Random.Range(0.6f, 0.9f);
    clone.localScale = new Vector3 (size, size, size);
    Destroy(clone.gameObject, 0.02f);

    //Shake the Camera
    camShake.Shake(camShakeAmt, camShakeLength);

    //Play shoot sound
    audioManger.PlaySound(weaponShootSound);
}
```

Comment: Can you show method `Effect`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I added the effect method to the orgianl post. Thanks!!

Comment: I am still having the issue do you have any suggestions. Please I am getting fusterated with it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually either I am feeling dumb or don't know. I cannot find your bullet spawning, and behaviour of your bullet? Do you have a separate script for bullet? If yes then please show it and also point out where you are spawning your bullet

Comment: The bullet is spawning in the shoot method. The bullet spawns with a raycast. It starts at the firePointPosition which is an empty game object at the end of the gun and is an child of the gun. Then the transform.right which I dont really understand. It should to my understanding shoot the right of the transform but no matter where I point the gun it alwasy shoots the right. If you could help on why this is happening that would be great!

Comment: Just thought I would let you know that I was able to figure it out I had to chnage the hitpos in the shoot method to a firepoint.right instead of having just the firePointPosition. Thanks for all your help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

So, just to make sure we're on the same page. There are to "types" of vectors: Direction and Position.

Position vectors are really just a "direction from zero" but for out purposes they behave differently. You use these to **LOCATE** objects

Direction vectors indicate a displacement in xyz space. You use these to **MOVE** objects.

Just so we're clear, this line doesn't make much sense.

```
Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, (firePointPosition)*100, Color.cyan);
```

You're just scaling the vector in regards to the origin. Since you're debuging a raycast (position, direction) rather than a point to point (position, position), you should actually use:

```
Debug.DrawRay(firePointPosition,firePoint.right * 100);
```

---

In your situation, the fire point is a location vector, and you need a direction vector to determine the final location of your projectile.

You're using transform.right which should work as long as you are rotating the transform (it only changes when the transform rotates). If you never rotate the transform, the projectiles will *always* fire straight right.

So make sure that transform has actual rotation. In the inspector view, highlight the gameobject and view the axes to make sure things are rotating as they should be.

Comment: Note: make sure to have your gimbal in Local mode, not Global when checking the scene view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I really appricate it! I did what you suggested and I am still getting the same result. I checked the gameObjects rotation and the red arrow is always rotating in the correct way. I added the effect method to the orginal post if that helps in any way please let me know what other suggestions you have. Thanks!!

Comment: I am still having the same issue do you have any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Just thought I would let you know that I was able to figure it out I had to chnage the hitpos in the shoot method to a firepoint.right instead of having just the firePointPosition. Thanks for all your help I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.